# Connecting the dots on ApplicationCommands.Copy and RichTextBox paste

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom class `MyClass` in which I do the following:

```
public class MyClass
{    
    static MyClass()
    {
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(MyClass), new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Copy, handleCopyExecute));
    }

    private static void handleCopyExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //When Ctrl+C is pressed and the class instance has focus, we arrive at this code. 
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(GetMyDataObject());
    }
}
```

I also have a `RichTextBox` set up as follows:

```
public class MyRichTextBox:RichTextBox
{
    public MyRichTextBox
    {
         DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this,pastingHandler);
    }

    private void pastingHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
       //When Ctrl+V is pressed, we typically arrive at this code, however nothing happens (nothing pastes) if the last copy operation was MyClass.

    }
}
```

I have no problem setting the clipboard data object as shown in MyClass, but the rich text box doesn't respond to Ctrl+V presses, which seems to indicate the app isn't aware there is data waiting to be copied. I thought the ApplicationCommands.Copy handler would provide this signal that data is ready to be pasted. How do I connect these two so that the `RichTextBox` paste is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to my problem was a simple one that took a day of stepping through source code to understand.

In the `GetMyDataObject` step listed above, I was creating a `DataObject` with only one type of data, i.e. `DataObject.SetData("MyType",myval)` which the CommandManager cannot understand. In the WPF source code, the paste event would get blocked and never route to the RichTextBox.

The solution was to add a known type to my DataObject in addition to my type. I simply called `DataObject.SetData("Text",myval.ToString())` to give some additonal trivial information to the paste. It executes smoothly now.

Moral of the story: If you need to create a DataObject for Copy/Cut/Paste, give it multiple types.